# Get sub menu to stay down we click inside subb menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

How can I do so that the menu does not ride up when I click inside subbmenyn?
(Subbmenu will go up when you click on the main link or outside.)
Can it be done without javascript?
Then the menu goes over and works with muse over if you do not have javascript enabled.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/realitylab/6ddvq/3/)

**CODE:**

```
$('.nav > ul').toggleClass('no-js js');
$('.nav .js ul').hide();

$(document).on("click", function(e) {
    var $elem = $(e.target);
    if ($elem.hasClass('clicker')) {
        $('.nav .js ul').not($elem.next('ul')).hide();
        $elem.next("ul").slideToggle();
    } else {
        $('.nav .js ul').hide();
    }
})
```

Comment: By the way, you've defined multiple elements in your html with the same id... Also you have a `div` element nested within a `ul` ...

Comment: update it so that it is class now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply change the else to check that the clicked element isn't in that container, and that it's not the container. 
Though you have several elements with the same Id, you should change them to a class

```
<div class="contentHolder">
```

so your jQuery  would then be

```
else if (!$($elem).parents('.contentHolder').length && !$elem.hasClass('contentHolder')) {
```

And you'll need to update the CSS `#contentHolder` to `.contentHolder`

http://jsfiddle.net/6ddvq/5/

Comment: You have updated your CSS for #contentHolder to .contentHolder too? http://jsfiddle.net/6ddvq/4/

Comment: I interpreted that wrong, it works now,
How about if I do not have javascript enabled?

Comment: I also just added that it also isn't the container itself. Try it now.

Comment: If you don't have javascript enabled, it's not going to show/hide ever.

Comment: yes, it seems to work without javascript too :)

Thanks for your help and Happy New Year!